# Should I include sources when asking questions that include some other user's idea?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In my math question, I'm trying to show the progress I've made for solving the problem. But it includes some other user's idea. Should I specify where I got the idea from?

Comment: I can't think of much of a reason to not include sources. Can you?

Comment: In theory, anything that helps users understand the question is good... but this can get out of hand, of course. Use your best judgement.

Comment: Yes. Get used to academic honesty about where your ideas come from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, always credit generously.